# Cascaded command bindings possible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MainWindow that contains multiple views using MVVM. In fact the MainWindow holds only a list of Models and each time a Model is added it creates a View (here a UserControl) and associates the DataContext (Model) to the View. Each view is put into a separate TabItem in a TabControl.

The Model itself has a CommandBindingsCollection and assigns this command bindings to the View. This means that for example F10 is available multiple times, but should only the active View should react on F10.

But, F10 does not work at all. Only if I assign the CommandBinding to the MainWindow it works, but this makes the View dependent on the UserControl and this is not what I want, since I wnat to create the View as independent as possible from the MainWindow.

The only solution I have is to make this dynamically intercepting the change of the current TabItem and add/remove the commands for the active View. Currently everything works without code, but then I have to write code for it.

Attached is a code of the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
</Window>



 using System.Windows;                 

 namespace WpfApplication3
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                PluginControl aControl = new PluginControl();
                Content = aControl;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the code of the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.PluginControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding myCommand}" Content="PushMe" Focusable="False"/>
        <Label Content="Nothing pressed" Name="myLabel"/>            
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PluginControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PluginControl : UserControl
    {
        public RoutedCommand myCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public PluginControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            myCommand = new RoutedCommand();
            myCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F10));

            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(myCommand, myCommandHandler));
        }

        private void myCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs executed)
        {
            myLabel.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have set the Button to Focusable false, since I want to have the command working in general, not only when the button is focused. I'm I missing something or thinking in a wrong direction, that making adding a CommandBinding does not implicitly mean that the command does work without binding it?

Adding the Command to the MainWindow itself works.

Any help?

Comment: can you show the situation with a bit of code? Sorry if I sound confused.

Comment: Not sure if I understood but don't you want just know how to propagate F10 keypress to viewmodel in MVVM way?

Comment: I added an example. The problem is that obviously adding command bindings to some child control is not propagated as tunneling events from the MainWindow to the child control.